# openlayers, how to get all modified features together from vector source

Tags: openlayers, postgis, geoserver

1. I am trying to Edit and save features in openlayers.
   While doing so, I got stuck at one place where I want to get **all** modified features **together** from vector source. Is there any solution?
2. Also suggest how can I implement feature audit functionality using openlayers, geoserver, postgis. Any solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to `addfeature` `removefeature` and `changefeature` events to get informed and store feature modifications.

```
source.on ('changefeature', (e) => {
  // e.feature has changed
  // do something with it...
  e.feature._state = 'update';
});
```

Look at WFS-T and functions as writeTransaction to send modifications to server (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WFS-WFS.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It solves my query. However, I have a following doubt.

Is there any optimized and faster way to fetch all updated features(_state='updated').

Comment: You can store updates in the source when update : `source._updates.push (e.feature)`